# Deleting a record in Laravel 5.3 using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm getting the next error:

> jquery-2.2.4.min.js:4 DELETE http://company.dev/admin/portfolio/settings/category/delete/7 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm not sure what it is because I think I have the right route and also giving the csrf token (still fairly new to laravel)

Route:

```
   Route::delete('/admin/portfolio/settings/category/delete/{id}', [
      'as' => 'categoryDelete',
      'uses' => 'PortfolioController@destroy'
   ]);`enter code here`
```

Ajax:

```
   $(".deleteProduct").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var token = $(this).data("token");
        $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/admin/portfolio/settings/category/delete/"+id,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    data: {
                        "id": id,
                        "_method": 'DELETE',
                        "_token": token
                    },
                    success: function ()
                    {
                        console.log("it Work");
                    }
                });

        console.log("It failed");
    });
```

Delete button:

```
 <button class="deleteProduct" data-id="{{ $category->category_id }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" >Delete Category</button>
```

Delete function:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    Category::find($id)->delete();

    return response()->json([
        'success' => 'Record has been deleted successfully!'
    ]);
}
```

Comment: in case of token problem it wouldn't be 500

Comment: Can you try:

`Route::delete('/admin/portfolio/settings/category/delete/{id}', 'PortfolioController@destroy');`

and `die('route works')`; inside controller (destroy function).
Is the delete only http method called in your request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your Controller or Model has some error. May be syntax error. Try checking Console > Network > XHR. The error ajax request will be in red color if you are using Google Chrome.

Comment: Awesome I didn't know that existed ! Thanks alot!

Comment: I would suggest checking the application logs which should contain the full stack trace rather then console output, unless you provide full stack trace to your users ;)

Comment: @jakub wrona makes sense :)